# Too many chained conditions in if-else

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using Rails. How to best rewrite the `country_photo`?

```
# country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :zones

  def country_photo
    if !zones.blank? && !zones.first.shops.blank? && !zones.first.shops.first.photos.blank?
      zones.first.shops.first.photos.first.url(:picture_preview)
    end
  end
end

# zones.rb
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :country
  has_many :zone_shops
  has_many :shops, :through => :zone_shops
end

# zone_shop.rb
class ZoneShop < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zone
  belongs_to :shop
end

# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base  

end
```

Comment: When you have those much deep association you can't do anything. But one way to avoid deep association is to store `photo_id` which `belongs_to :photo` in your `country` model. One more way to do what u did without if-else is `zones.try(:first).try(:shops).try(:first).try(:photos).try(:first).try(:url).try(:picture_preview)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `!x.blank?` -> `x.present?`. Anyway, if you are ok with doing assignations in `if`s (they are pretty common in Ruby), you can write:

```
def country_photo
  if (zone = zones.first) &&
     (shop = zone.shops.first) &&
     (photo = shop.photos.first) 
    photo.url(:picture_preview)
  end
end
```

If you like fancy abstractions, with [Ick](http://ick.rubyforge.org/) you can write:

```
def country_photo
  zones.first.maybe { |zone| zone.shops.first.photos.first.url(:picture_preview) }
end
```

Comment: I gotta install Ick huh? Reluctant to install one new gem just for this.

Comment: @Victor: added a more orthodox approach. In any case note that these are simple abstraction you can write yourself on your extensions module (`Object#maybe` is implemented in 4/5 lines).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to show an image in a view, I would do something like this:

```
# show.html.haml
- if @country.photo
  image_tag @country.photo.url(:picture_preview)

# country.rb
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  def photo
    zones.first.photo unless zones.blank?
  end
end

# zone.rb
class Zone < ActiveRecord::Base
  def photo
    shops.first.photo unless shops.blank?
  end
end

# shop.rb
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  def photo
    photos.first unless photos.blank?
  end
end
```