# Too many conditionals for an if statement?

Tags: ruby, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make sure the roman numeral entered is valid. My strategy is to start with the first one or two characters, and if anything after that in the string is invalid, then I tell them to re-enter their number. If I do it this way, I need to make a conditional for D, CD, C, XC, L, XL, X, IX, V, IV, and I. below is just for CM. Is the way I pasted below the best way to write this conditional statement or is there a prettier way?

```
string = "CMCMD"
integer_num = 0

if string[0..1] = "CM"
  if string[2..-1].include? "M" || string[2..-1].include? "CD" || string[2..-1].include? "D" || string[2..-1].include "CM" || string[2..-1].include? "C"
    puts "This is invalid. Please enter your roman numeral correctly."
  else
    add 900 to integer_num and slice CM off the beginning of the string.
  end
end
```

I looked at the docs, and a couple things on S.O like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619559/too-many-chained-conditions-in-if-else).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below using [`Enumerable#any?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F)

```
 if ["M","CD","D","CM","C"].any?{|e| string[2..-1].include? e }
```

or

```
 ary = %w(M CD D CM C)
 if ary.any?(&string[2..-1].method(:include?))
```

Comment: Thank you! that is beautiful. Will accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

This is a method from my personal library that converts a Roman numeral string into a number. It is not clear in your question what kind of strings you consider as invalid. My method tries to maximally make sense out of the Roman characters.

```
class String
  RomanToI = {"i"=>1, "v"=>5, "x"=>10, "l"=>50, "c"=>100, "d"=>500, "m"=>1000}
  def roman_to_i!
    prev = 1000
    downcase.each_char.inject(0) do |i, d|
      raise "Invalid string as Roman numeral" unless d = RomanToI[d]
      (d <= prev) ? prev = d : i -= (prev * 2)
      i += d
    end
  end
end

"mmxiv".roman_to_i! # => 2014
"a".roman_to_i! # => Invalid string as Roman numeral.
```

Comment: That is very impressive. I don't even really understand your code fully, sawa, but the fact that it works in such a small amount of code is very cool.

Answer (score 0):

```
(['M', 'D', 'C'] & string[2..-1].chars).any?
```

There's no need to check `string[2..-1]` for `'CD'`, as `'CD'` cannot be present unless 'C' and 'D' are also present.  Same for `'CM'`.

The first and second parts of `string` really should be variables.  Perhaps do something like this:

```
cases = {'CM' => {suffix: 'CMD', illegal: ['M', 'D', 'C']},
         'CD' => {...},
         ...}

def invalid?(str, illegal)
  (str.chars & illegal).any?
end

def check_all(cases)
  cases.each do |c, v|  
    if invalid?(v[:suffix], v[:illegal])
      ...
    end
  end
end
```